# jquery :last-child did not work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

jQuery `$("div span[z*='w']:last-child").css({color: "red"});`

and the html

```
<div>
   <span z="ww">Sam</span>  <!-- Didn't works -->
   <span>Sam 2</span>
</div>
<div>
    <span z="ww">Glen,</span>
    <span z="ww">David</span> <!-- Works -->
</div>
```

How  to select the span from the first div?

Live example http://jsbin.com/izubaj/edit#javascript,html,live

Comment: Have you tried `:first`? http://jsfiddle.net/b6b5F/

Comment: `:first` isn't a solution for me. I need to select all spans..

Comment: If you need all just use `$("div span[z*='w']")` without any additions. http://jsfiddle.net/b6b5F/1/

Comment: So you want to select the last span in every div that has `z*=w`? Please be more specific, nobody wants to spend time finding out what do you need help with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector actually chooses the `span` elements and then applies the last child pseudo selector to that collection, try the following:

```
$("div").find('span[z*="w"]:last').css({color: "red"});
```

[See here](http://jsbin.com/izubaj/5/edit) for update.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("span[z*='w']:last", 'div').css({color: "red"});
```

Comment: This is actually just another version of rich.okelly's solution. Both work, bot I prefer to have the target selector in front.

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding the question, but I think you want the `span` that has "Sam 2" as well as "David".

```
<div>
    <span z="ww">Sam</span>  <!-- Didn't works -->
    <span>Sam 2</span>
</div>
```

If that's the case, try:

```
$('div span[z*="w"]').siblings(':last-child').css({color: 'red'});
```